# Error starting release: Working tree has untracked files

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven JGit-Flow Plugin in order to automate some of the release process. Unfortunately I'm hitting this problem when trying to start new release using `mvn jgitflow:release-start`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project <myProjectName>: Error starting release: Error starting release: Working tree has untracked files
```

However I cannot see and untracked files here (nor on master):

```
git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Any idea how does Maven JGit-Flow Plugin find untracked files?

Comment: Also tried with git ls-files --other --directory --exclude-standard... still no untracked files whatsoever

Comment: It is open source, so you can check it up to see exactly how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by allowing untracked files:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: allowing where?
your project? intellij? where?

Comment: @Eduardo In the Project pom.xml

Answer (score 7):

A look into `.git/jgitflow.log` will show which files are found to be untracked by jgitflow. In my case I found the line:

```
GitHelper:         _  -- untracked: .DS_Store _
```

I have a global gitignore file

```
$ git config --get core.excludesfile
~/.gitignore_global
```

where `.DS_Store` is set as an exclusion. Unfortunately jgitflow seems not to be aware of this setting. So I added the exclusion to the project’s `.gitignore` file with:

```
 ### Mac OSX
.DS_Store
```

After that `mvn jgitflow:release-start` worked as expected.

Comment: I found the same logs in jgitflow.log but i already have .DS_Store entry in my .gitignore file and git doesnt seem to complain about it

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Why should git complain? My issue was jgitflow complaining about an untacked .DS_Store file, but I could not see anything untracked via `git status`.

Comment: same here. I resorted to using `<allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>` in my pom

Answer (score 0):

Please check for all the maven generated and IDE generated files and folders. Add them to `.gitignore`.

Following are the files and folders that are ignored for me. I am using maven 3 and IntelliJ. Here is the content of `.gitignore`:

```
### IntelliJ Idea Project Files.

# IntelliJ project files
.idea
*.iml
out
gen
target/

### Java Files
*.class

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
.settings
# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

For most of the people following will fix the issue, if they are not using IntelliJ:

```
target/
```